Conditional options in <select> using signals
I have a select that should show options based on the status of a game.
Code:
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Status" [(ngModel)]="selectedGame().status">
    @if (selectedGame().status === GameStatus.played || selectedGame().status === GameStatus.forfeit) {
        <option [value]="GameStatus.played">{{ GameStatus.played | gameStatus }}</option>
        <option [value]="GameStatus.forfeit">{{ GameStatus.forfeit | gameStatus }}</option>
    } @else {
        <option [value]="GameStatus.notPlayed">{{ GameStatus.notPlayed | gameStatus }}</option>
        <option [value]="GameStatus.postponed">{{ GameStatus.postponed | gameStatus }}</option>
    } 
</select>

Initially the options are rendered correctly based on the status. However after I swap between one of the available options it will then always show the options from the else block.
I tried to debug but can't find the problem. When switching from 'Played' to 'Forfeit' the status is actually set correctly from '1' to '3'. Maybe somewhere in the process the value is emptied and the signal is somehow not sending a notification when the new value is set?
SOLUTION:
The problem was that the type of the selectedGame().status property was being changed from GameStatus (enum of numbers) to string when updating the signal. That's why I was always hitting the else-block.
The solution was to use [ngValue] instead of [value].
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Status" [(ngModel)]="selectedGame().status">
    @if (selectedGame().status === GameStatus.played || selectedGame().status === GameStatus.forfeit) {
        <option [ngValue]="GameStatus.played">{{ GameStatus.played | gameStatus }}</option>
        <option [ngValue]="GameStatus.forfeit">{{ GameStatus.forfeit | gameStatus }}</option>
    } @else {
        <option [ngValue]="GameStatus.notPlayed">{{ GameStatus.notPlayed | gameStatus }}</option>
        <option [ngValue]="GameStatus.postponed">{{ GameStatus.postponed | gameStatus }}</option>
    }
</select>


When your signal contains an object, and a property of the object changes, the signal is not evaluated again, because referential equality (=== comparison) is used by default. So what you are seeing is expected behavior. I don't see a reason why selectedGame() needs to be a signal in the first place, from the given code. If that's the case, an easy fix would be to get rid of this signal and create a selectedGameStatus signal instead which only holds the status, and use it like the following (without parentheses):
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGameStatus">

You can also try to mess with the signal equality function, but I advice against it in your case.

Thanks for your answer. I use the selectedGame signal for more than just this piece of code. It is used in multiple places in the component. So I guess I can checkout the signal equality function.

I understand the signal behaviour here, but I feel like it makes things more complicated sometimes..

So I tried this but is does not seem to work :/.

This is my version of the solution. It's simple, you need to use update method on the signal to propagate the changes to the UI. Since there are no buttons you can use ngModelChange to trigger the update.
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export enum GameStatus {
  forfeit = 'forfeit',
  played = 'played',
  notPlayed = 'notPlayed',
  postponed = 'postponed',
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <button (click)="setStatus('played')">played</button>
  <button (click)="setStatus('notPlayed')">notPlayed</button>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Status" [ngModel]="selectedGame().status" (ngModelChange)="setStatus($event)">
    @if (selectedGame().status === GameStatus.played || selectedGame().status === GameStatus.forfeit) {
        <option [value]="GameStatus.played">{{ GameStatus.played }}</option>
        <option [value]="GameStatus.forfeit">{{ GameStatus.forfeit }}</option>
    } @else {
        <option [value]="GameStatus.notPlayed">{{ GameStatus.notPlayed }}</option>
        <option [value]="GameStatus.postponed">{{ GameStatus.postponed }}</option>
        <option [value]="GameStatus.played">{{ GameStatus.played }}</option>
    } 
</select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  GameStatus = GameStatus;
  selectedGame = signal({
    status: '',
  });

  setStatus(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedGame.update((prev: any) => {
      prev.status = value;
      return prev;
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, but I do not have any buttons or anything to trigger the setStatus method.
I have tried something like this:
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Status" [ngModel]="selectedGame().status" (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedGameStatus($event.target)">
But no luck. Still the same problem.

@jasperheeren Please note, there is no options to switch to the else statement, so I added an option, and it works great. Do check out my stackblitz, updated my answer!

I checked your Stackblitz solution and it is working fine. However in my project I can't get it to work. I copied your exact solution without the buttons, but no luck.

@jasperheeren try checking the package.json and paste the same versions to the stackblitz and share back, maybe it a version of angular problem!

Hey Naren, I found the problem, check my update in the problem above. Now looking why this is happening. Thanks for the help :).

@jasperheeren no problem!
